# R: How to join two data tables by nearest single time-date?

Tags: r, join, data.table

I hope someone might help me on this. I have two tables that need to be joined on the nearest date. Below are some example data:

```
new <- data.table( date = as.Date( c( "2016-03-02", "2016-03-04", 
                                     "2016-04-02" ) ), data.new = c( "t","u","v" ) )

old <- data.table( date = as.Date( c( "2016-03-01", "2016-03-07", 
                                     "2016-04-02", "2015-03-02" ) ), 
               data.old = c( "a","b","c","d" ) )
```

I am looking for some solutions using the data.table package. I've found this solution:

```
setkeyv(new, "date")
setkeyv(old, "date")
combined <- new[old, roll = "nearest"]
```

The solution looks like this:

```
> new
         date data.new
1: 2016-03-02        t
2: 2016-03-04        u
3: 2016-04-02        v

> old
         date data.old
1: 2016-03-01        a
2: 2016-03-07        b
3: 2016-04-02        c
4: 2015-03-02        d

> combined
         date data.new data.old
1: 2015-03-02        t        d
2: 2016-03-01        t        a
3: 2016-03-07        u        b
4: 2016-04-02        v        c
```

But this is not exactly what i want to achieve, see desired output below:
In this particular case, dates "2015-03-02" and "2016-03-01" don't have a corresponding match in "new". Only the nearest date "2016-03-01" gets a matched value in the end, leaving the matched value for "2015-03-02" as NA.

```
> combined
         date data.new data.old
1: 2015-03-02        NA       d
2: 2016-03-01        t        a
3: 2016-03-07        u        b
4: 2016-04-02        v        c
```

I would appreciate your help! A follow-up question would be, what if there are multiple IDs? That means, what if the data need to be grouped? Thanks!

Comment: I think yours corresponding match in new is `2016-03-02`.

Comment: Yes maybe i need to be more precise. What i mean is that 2015-03-02 and 2016-03-01 don't have a EXACT corresponding match in "new". Maybe this is clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imperfect roll result is due to the different length of `old` and `new`.
Then the solution is very intuitive. In order to let them have same size, I will `rbind` some row to the head of the shorter data.table `new`.

```
new <- data.table( date = as.Date( c( "2016-03-02", "2016-03-04", 
                                     "2016-04-02" ) ), data.new = c( "t","u","v" ) )

old <- data.table( date = as.Date( c( "2016-03-01", "2016-03-07", 
                                     "2016-04-02", "2015-03-02" ) ), 
               data.old = c( "a","b","c","d" ) )

head_row <- data.table(date = old[,min(date)],
                       data.new = NA)
new <- rbind(head_row,new)
setkey(new,date)
setkey(old,date)
new[old, roll = "nearest"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! This works, but actually i have a much bigger dataset where the data.table new has much fewer rows than data.table old, e.g. 10 versus 200 rows. I am wondering is there any functions that take care of this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Of course this method can be extended. The key is to build the `head_row` as the difference size of `new` and `old`.

Comment: Ah i see! So that means as long as i have two datasets that are of same size, applying roll = nearest will only merge the nearest date. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I think so.  You can check it with a larger data set.